# XML Parsing error in Flex

Tags: apache-flex

I am passing a XML document form the Java to Flex using Remote Object. 
My XML is as follows

```
"
<root
<dept ID="1" Name="RND"
    <Emp ID="1" Name="Aj"/>
</dept>
<dept ID="2" Name="ENG">
<Emp ID="1" Name="Aj"/>
</dept>
<dept ID="3" Name="MECH">
    <Emp ID="1" Name="Aj"/>
</dept>
</root>
"
```

In Flex i am trying to access using below code

```
treeData = event.result as XML;
deptTree.dataProvider = treeData;
```

When i am trying to access the result object and i am getting the below exception

"

```
[RPC Fault faultString="org.w3c.dom.DOMException : INVALID_CHARACTER_ERR: An invalid or illegal XML character is specified. " faultCode="Server.Processing" faultDetail="null"]
    at mx.rpc::AbstractInvoker/http://www.adobe.com/2006/flex/mx/internal::faultHandler()
    at mx.rpc::Responder/fault()
    at mx.rpc::AsyncRequest/fault()
    at NetConnectionMessageResponder/statusHandler()
    at mx.messaging::MessageResponder/status()
```

"
Please help me to resolve this issue.
Thanks in advance.
Aj

Answer (score 0):

```
<root
<dept ID="1" Name="RND"
```

Close root tag:

```
<root>
```

Comment: Thanks Alxx, but it was a typo error. In my code the XML is correct. In Java through XML Transformer i am able to print it. I am facing issue while accessing in FLEX using Remote Object